# Why escape key press does not work in Ace editor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ace-editor

I am using the Ace JavaScript editor with the vim keybindings. However, when I press the escape key (to get out of insert mode, for example), instead of getting me out of the mode, the editor un-focuses. What is the best way for me to capture this keypress in all modern browsers, and allow ace to use it?

To witness this problem, go [here](https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html), turn on vim keys, and then try to enter and escape a mode. I'm running the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in ace, but i am unable to reproduce it on firefox+windows7. On which OS do you see the issue, are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Linux, no console issue. Bug seems to be apparent in chromium for me too.

Comment: Just reproduced it running windows 10 and chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning off the Vimium extension, which I had installed everywhere, worked. Sorry to everyone who spent their time on this...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe attaching a `keydown` event to the document could help?

If the key pressed is escape, call `e.preventDefault` to prevent default browser behavior from happening.

```js
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
  if(e.key == "Escape") {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.key + " pressed");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did this. It does not work (still unfocuses and doesn't exit mode)

Comment: @vityavv Try changing the selector (e.g. use the div's id instead of `document`)

Comment: I did... the exact code was `document.getElementById("div").addEventListener('keydown", e => {...})` because I don't use jQuery